# Fantasy or sci-fi book involving a young male who finds a green crystal with mysterious power

Tags: story-identification, books

I think I read this book more than 10 years ago. I don't remember the exact details, but here's what I could make sense of:

- The cover featured the green crystal (which may or may not have been attached to a necklace with a black/dark color) and one or two individuals from the story displayed in the background.
- The story involved a male (think he was between 15-20) who found the crystal/necklace somewhow.
- He was either in college or high school.
- Not sure about the power of the previously mentioned crystal/necklace, but when wearing it, he could either hear voices, or was able to know future events (think it had some telepathic abilities too).
- At one point, he managed to use the crystal to know in advance if a certain abandoned/unused property would be worth buying, etc.
- There were "some" unknown beings (not sure if they were aliens or not), but they wanted to get the green crystal back from him.
- As it probably sounds, this was happening in modern time (roughly 19XX - 20XX)

That's all I could think of. I can't recall anything else. Unsure if it was specifically fantasy or sci-fi, but I know it was probably either or both...
The focus of the story was mainly around the previously mentioned green crystal/necklace.

Comment: When did you read this?  Did the main character get to keep the crystal in the end?

Comment: I read it years ago (think it was more than 10 years ago). I never finished it as far as I'm aware, which is why I was curious about the title of the book so i could finish it :) @DavidW

Comment: Thankfully, knowing the main focus was that green crystal make things easier to narrow down, or so I thought...turn out not knowing the title make things that much harder...